# How to access nested JSON object key and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to access the key and values of my nested array like this:

```
var obj = $.getJSON("mydata.json", function() {
    console.log( "load success" );
});

Object.keys(obj[2].type).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

But I get an error.

Here's the structure of the JSON file:

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "nd": "nd1",
        "cat": "cat1"
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "id": 100
    }
],
"types": [
            {
                "type": "one",
                "image": "image001"
            },
            {
                "type": "two",
                "image": "image002"
            },
            {
                "type": "three",
                "image": "image003"
            }
        ]
```

}

My goal is to get a list of values of:

> one two three

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `var vals = obj.types.map((x) =>  x.image; });`

Comment: There is no key 2 for the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

You have to firstly acces to object.types attribute, then iterate on it to retrieve every type.

```js
var object = {
  "nodes": [{
    "nd": "nd1",
    "cat": "cat1"
  }],
  "links": [{
    "id": 100
  }],
  "types": [{
    "type": "one",
    "image": "image001"
  }, {
    "type": "two",
    "image": "image002"
  }, {
    "type": "three",
    "image": "image003"
  }]
};


function parseJson(object){
    object.types.forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(key.type);
    });
}

parseJson(object);
```

--- update to anwer question in comment ---

you could enclose the code in a function, and call it when you load your json:

```
$.getJSON("mydata.json", function(data) {
    parseJson(data);
});
```

Comment: this works, but how about load it from an external file. how do I do it with `getJSON` command?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with this code:

```js
var obj = {
"nodes": [
    {
        "nd": "nd1",
        "cat": "cat1"
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "id": 100
    }
],
"types": [
            {
                "type": "one",
                "image": "image001"
            },
            {
                "type": "two",
                "image": "image002"
            },
            {
                "type": "three",
                "image": "image003"
            }
        ]   
};

Object.keys(obj["types"]).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(obj["types"][key].image);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys(obj[2].type)` doesn't really make sense here. You're not iterating over the properties of any object, you're accessing the same property in a set of objects. This is what `map` does.

```
var types = obj.types.map(x => x.type);
```

Comment: isn't `map(x => x.type)` a TypeScript syntax?

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu: Probably that as well, but it's also EcmaScript 6.

Answer (score 1):

$.getJSON returns a promise because it is asynchronous, but you can set your variable in your callback:

```
var obj;
$.getJSON("mydata.json", function(data) {
    obj = data;
    Object.keys(obj[2].type).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(key, obj[key]);
    });
});
```

[link to documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Answer (score 1):

You should post the error that you get, but I can tell you that the problem is that your output code executes before the JSON object has been loaded.
Try this:

```
$.getJSON("mydata.json", function(obj) {
    console.log( "load success" );
    Object.keys(obj[2].type).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(key, obj[key]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional way to do it in js :

```
    var types = $.getJSON("mydata.json").done(function(response) {
       return Object.keys(data["types"]).map(function(element){
            return element.type;
        }).join(' ');
    });            

   console.log(types);
```